pywin32 module was not found
pywin32 was not able use in python;
python version 3.12
pywin32 module version 306
I don't know the reason to solve the error.
pywin32 module not found.
I correctly set the path but doesn't work.
I want, know about to solve this problem.
any body know about this guide me solve this problem.

Check [SO]: How do I ask a good question? or
[SO]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))
for more asking related details.  You don't need to set any path. Check [SO]: ImportError: No module named win32com.client (@CristiFati's answer)
for more details.
